# BlackBerry JDE 7.1 MDS working, application in simulator not connecting

Tags: http, blackberry, connection, simulator, jde

I've been developing tiny BlackBerry applications since OS 5.0 using the BlackBerry JDE software provided by RIM. I did not have issues using the simulator till the Java applet crashed when requesting code signatures. I had to download JDE 7.1 (the latest) in order to get my app's signed.

Now however, the 9900 (OS 7.0) simulator in BlackBerry 7.1 is running together with the MDS. I can visit websites using the simulated browser or use a simulated Twitter application. However all my applications now suddenly don't make any HTTP connection with my servers (no activity in running MDS).

As far as I know the HTTPConnection library is not an deprecated API. What could the cause of this problem be? Anybody had a similar issue after updating their JDE software from BlackBerry?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be exactly there: `HttpConnection` needs different parameters appended to the URL depending on the transport type, while the newer `ConnectionFactory` doesn't. MDS simulator is like connecting via BES, so you'll need to append append the correct suffix:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-make-an-HTTP-or-socket-connection/ta-p/445879

Starting with OS 5.0, you can use `ConnectionFactory` and get rid of this kind of stuff.